# Mesh from heightmap in Ogre3D

Tags: c++, ogre3d

Using the Ogre3D engine (C++), I would like to generate a mesh from a grayscale heightmap. I know that the Terrain tools can do that but I just want a simple mesh. What would be the best way to do that? This sounds pretty basic but I can't find my way in the Ogre3d doc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is extract all the height values and pump them into an [**Ogre::ManualObject**](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1ManualObject.html).

Then call ManualObject::convertToMesh(...) for the conversion.

Fire up a MeshSerializer and use it to save the mesh out to a file.

```
MeshPtr pmo = mo.convertToMesh( "GrassBladesMesh" );
MeshSerializer ser;
ser.exportMesh( pmo.getPointer(), "grass.mesh" );
```

See Ogre::ManualObject link above for more info. HTH

Comment: Thanks, this ManualObject looks very handy, I'll give it a shot!